# Interval id counter keeps growing after clearing old one

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following intervals, the id of the first interval is 1, even that I cleared it the second interval gets id of 2. is there a way the I can reset the interval's id when it cleared? such that the second interval will have id of 1.

```
let it=setInterval(function(){
console.log(it);// prints 1
},1000);

clearInterval(1);

let it2=setInterval(function(){
console.log(it2); // prints 2
},1000);
```

Comment: change it to clearInterval(it) and this should work.

Comment: Why do you think you need the handle of the second timer to be `1`? Also note that there is **no** guarantee the handle of the first timer will be `1`. Only that it will be greater than `0`.

Comment: `it` is random id, You can't predict it so you first grab the `it` and clear it as `clearInterval(it);`

Comment: I get 2 and 3 here `let it=setInterval(function(){
console.log(it);/* prints 2 */
clearInterval(it);
},1000);

let it2=setInterval(function(){
console.log(it2); /* prints 3 */
clearInterval(it2);
},1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...is there a way the I can reset the interval's id when it cleared?

No. Every time you call `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, a **new** handle value is created. This is [per specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers). The **only** thing you can rely on about the handle is that, in the browser environment, it will be [a whole number greater than `0`](http://%20let%20handle%20be%20an%20implementation-defined%20integer%20that%20is%20greater%20than%20zero%20that%20will%20identify%20the%20timeout%20to%20be%20set%20by%20this%20call%20in%20the%20list%20of%20active%20timers.) and won't be the same as any other timer handle that's been provided by previous calls in the same realm (roughly, on that page). (On Node.js it's not a number, it's an object.) (The fact it's never `0` is handy; you can use `0` as a "no timer is set" value for the handle variable.)